# Is C# ready for Dynamics AX 2012 R3

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Recently, I have been using WinRT and WP to access Dynamics NAV/AX thru Web services using C#. Understand both of them are not using C# as the programming language. I wanted to learn to program Dynamics AX but find hard to learn all over again using X++. So I am posting this question in hope to find out what are the new opportunities in AX 2012 R3 has to offer to C# developer, will C# be the programming language? This will help me a lot for Client side such as WinRT and WP and Server side using C# as well.

Thanks

Comment: What level is your C#? X++ is easy, get a head start on other .net devs who may come into this area and learn some...

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but R3 should be no different than R2 in this respect.

Most of AX is programmed in X++ and MorphX objects and this is not going to change in the near term.

That said AX objects are accessible from the C# and C# is callable from X++. An object is either C# or X++ and even container objects are not the same but similar, example `Map` in X++ and `SortedDictionary` in C#.

Comment: should be even easier if/when x++ hits the .net stack